# Does Cabal Paladin's ability trigger when playing an artifact land?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a [Cabal Paladin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCabal%20Paladin%5d) onto the battlefield, and I play an artifact land, such as [Seat of the Synod](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSeat%20of%20the%20Synod%5d), does the Cabal Paladin's ability trigger?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it doesn't trigger. Lands are played but not 'cast'. There is a ruling below the card in Gatherer which explicitly states so:

> Lands are never cast, so abilities that trigger “whenever you cast a historic spell” won’t trigger if you play a legendary land. They also won’t trigger if a card on the battlefield transforms into a legendary land, as the Ixalan and Rivals of Ixalan double-faced cards do.

Comment: Yes. Moreover - I only realized it now - on Seat of theSynod there is also explicitly written: "this isn't a spell" ...! however...thanks, Glorfinder.

Comment: All of this starts from the idea of ​​bringing together cards from Mirrodin and cards from Dominaria in a single deck. The former are characterized by the ability "Affinity for artifacts ", which links very well with Dominaria's concept of" historic spell ". Too bad that Mirrodin was characterized by "Artifact Lands" too, which then were rightly and forever banned. Basically, it is right: an "artifact land" seems to me ..just a contradiction in terms !! Thus, the bond doesn't always work well, because artifact lands don't count as historic spells.